# Using numeric_limits to default parameter values

Tags: c++, templates, numeric-limits

I have a template statistics class that has range parameters.

```
template <typename T>
class limitStats
{
public:
    limitStats(T mx, T min) :
      max(mx),
      min(mn),
      range(mx-mn)
    {;}

private:
    const T max;
    const T min;
    const T range;
}
```

I would like to put default values of maximum and minimum allowable values, but the minimum value is not the same for floating point and integer types.

Normally I can write

```
T min_val = numeric_limits<T>::isinteger ? numeric_limits<T>::min() : -numeric_limits<T>::max();
```

I have found that I can't use it as a default parameter

```
limitStats(T mx = std::numeric_limts<T>::max(), 
           T mn = numeric_limits<T>::isinteger ? numeric_limits<T>::min() : -numeric_limits<T>::max())
```

Is there a way of achieving something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to rethink your design. What are you trying to do with your `limitStats` that `std::numeric_limits` doesn't provide?

Don't replicate the badness of the design of `std::numeric_limits`. For example, `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()` is terribly misnamed. The minimum double is the additive inverse of the maximum double. `std::numeric_limits` is an abuse of notation and an abuse of templates. In my opinion, of course.

Your idea for `min` is ill-formed. Think about your default with respect to `limitStats<unsigned int>`.

With the defaults, your `range` is invalid for signed integers. For unsigned ints it replicates `max`, assuming you fix the problem with `limitStats<unsigned int>::min`. For floating point types, it is either invalid or replicates `max`, depending on what you mean by `limitStats<floating_point_type>::min`.

Does it even make sense to allow default values? You wouldn't even have this question if you simply don't provide defaults and make the default constructor private/unimplemented.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many syntax errors and typos that it is hard to tell which of those is your problem.

`numeric_limits` is a template, so you access it as `numeric_limits<int>::is_integer` or with a template type `numeric_limits<T>::max()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
boost::numeric::bounds<T>::lowest()
```

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/bounds.html

Comment: This will appear in C++0x as well, as `std::numeric_limits<T>::lowest()`.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same issue when trying to have a function signature like below in Windows on Visual studio while trying to create a DLL

```
int
GetARandomNum(
    int lowest = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
    int highest = std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
```

When trying various stuff, I decided to remove `#inlcude <windows.h>` from `stdafx.h` and things started building fine. Given that 'stdafx.h' is selected by default in VS and not including it or not does not make any difference to build error, I decided to simply move `#inlcude <windows.h>` from `stdafx'h` to cpp files wherever its needed which in case of a DLL project is usually in dllmain.cpp only. I do not know why `Windows.h` is messing with C+11 headers but I have seen similar issue earlier also.